# PHP Wkhtmltopdf not found

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I want to convert a webpage to PDF in PHP using the library wkhtmltopdf. I'm using this PHP wrapper mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf available [here](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf). I downloaded wkhtmltopdf binary from [here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-i386.tar.xz) and I used the below PHP code to point to it :

```
require  __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$pdfName = 'Invoice1.pdf';
$pdf = new mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf("some HTML code here");
$pdf->binary = __DIR__.'/wkhtmltopdf_0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
if (!$pdf->send($pdfName, true)) {
    echo $pdf->getError();
}
```

I'm getting this error: `sh: 1: /var/www/mysite/public_html/wkhtmltopdf_0.12.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found`

I don't understand why it is saying file not found. I tried to check with PHP if the file exists using `file_exists` and it returns true when I provide to it that location.

Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: If possible follow the instructions described on github and use composer.

Comment: Actually I'm doing it , I'm using composer.

Comment: Did you include the autoload file generated by composer?

Comment: Yes, I did not put it in my code here in stackoverflow, but yest I did it. Otherwise I would have gotten an error

Comment: I found the problem, the binary I was using is wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-i386.tar.xz, I changed it to wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz and it worked. I'm sure my OS is Ubuntu x86_64 not sure why amd64 is the only binary that worked.